# Can i write javascript code in jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to get the id value of a hyperlink from a html file into a jsp file.
My questions are:

- what is the better way to include a plain html file in jsp

  - is it    `<% @ include file="" %>`
  - or      `< jsp:include page=""/>`
- And can i write javascript code that is document.getelementbyid in this jsp file?:-)

Comment: To answer the second question, you need a <script> tag

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ (and your question is a bit hard to understand, by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Off course you can write java script code in jsp page. You need to use   tag for that.

Also you can access link element by using document.getElemenById(id_of_link). This will give you the link object. then you can access the properties of this object.

Hope this helps.

~Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

javascript on a jsp page is what it looks like on a html page

Comment: Try to show a bit of effort from yourself. There are plenty of posts that will tell you the difference between those two statements (i.e.: www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/105695, which is the first result on a google search) and the "code" you have written is not compilable.

Comment: I knw the diff b/w 2 statements.<jsp:include   page=" relative URL "   flush="true"/> Includes a file at the time the page isrequested. If you want to include the file at the time the page is translated, use the page directive with the include attribute instead.

Comment: then just think about your "problem", both directives will give you a similar result, it depends whether you want to make a request/response operation to your app server to obtain that HTML code or if just including it as it was a copy/paste operation would be enough. With the information you give is impossible to know if have tried anything at all or if you really know the scope of your "problem".

Comment: I need to get a hyperlink id into a jsp or an html file from an external .html file.i need to print that hyper link id.the hyperlink is in another html file